# Subclipse adding crap into my code on Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, svn, subclipse

My code is breaking because every time I try to recover from a previous revision of my code Subclipse keeps adding this weird notation/conments into my Javascript.

e.g.

```
    if (profanityCheck() == false)
<<<<<<< .working
    {
        var inputData = "";
        var newData = new Array();
=======
```

How do I stop it doing this?

Thanks

Comment: That code is there because there is a conflict in your code with another revision. It comments the working copy and usually another revision so you can compare the two and decide which to keep.

Comment: Learning svn with eclipse is an exercise in pain by the way (or it was for me).  Spending an hour just learning svn from the command line will give you a great foundation.  Maybe check out Version Control with Subversion (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That generally indicates there's a conflict between the version of the file in your workspace and the version from the SVN you're trying to switch to.

To fix it `Right-click -> Team -> Mark resolved`, then select the option that makes the most sense (probably use the incoming version of the file).

Comment: @loosebruce Do you mean the "Mark resolved" option? If so, then it means the file isn't actually in conflict now, but probably was at an earlier point. May be worth checking the version you're trying to switch to and making sure that doesn't have those lines in it. If it does, simply edit the file to take them out, then re-commit.